# Collapsing toolbar not showing Title Text

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm facing a weird issue related to Collapsing toolbar. When I rotate the screen, the collapsing toolbar hides the toolbar title when the collapsing toolbar is contracted.

The toolbar title shows up when the collapsing toolbar is expanded

Please screen the screenshots here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6ML4.jpg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="@dimen/collapsing_toolbar_title_margin_end"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/collapsing_toolbar_title_margin_start"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsedAppBarTextAppearance"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/world_image"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_countries"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_color"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Java code:

```
public class CountryListFragment extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.list_countries)
    RecyclerView mCountriesListRecyclerView;

    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_countries_list, container, false);

        //must bind for View Injection
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        // register event bus to receive events
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);

        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        initRecyclerView();
        populateRecyclerViewAdapter();
        return view;
    }

}
```

From the looks of it, the collapsing toolbar gets confused about the orientation of the device and animates the toolbar downwards instead of animating it upwards.

[image: You can even see the Toolbar title is out of place when the device orientation is changed.]

[image: The toolbar is completely hidden now upon orientation change from landscape to portrait]

[image: The toolbar title shows up when the collapsing toolbar is expanded]

[image: It goes away completely when the device is rotated again]

Comment: Please show the java code that set the toolbar as actionbar

Comment: it done please check